# how can i use a function from MyForm1.h in MyForm.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winforms

i have a funcion 'button1_click' in the header 'MyForm1.h'. I want to use this function in another header 'MyForm.h'. How can i do this?
i already included 'MyForm1.h' in 'MyForm.h'.

Comment: Call it? What doesn't work for you exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the reference into the form file then you should be able to call it from MyForm.h:

```
    #include "MyForm1.h"
    namespace MyForms {

    ... Initialize component and winform code ...

    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        MyForm1^ form1 = gcnew MyForm1;
        form1->ShowDialog();
        lblData->Text = form1->MyFunctionFromForm1();
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time to complete an example that does what you want. You need to define a button property, I defined this property in `MyForm1.h`, please read the following code carefully.

```
#pragma once

namespace Project7 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for MyForm1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
            
        }
         property Button^ Buttontest {
            Button^ get() {
                return  button1;
            }

            void set(Button^ value) {
                button1 = value;
            }
        }
        
    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button1;
    protected:

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(164, 90);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->button1->Text = L"button1";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm1::button1_Click);
            // 
            // MyForm1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 261);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Name = L"MyForm1";
            this->Text = L"MyForm1";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        MessageBox::Show("sda");
        
    }
    };
}
```

In `MyForm.h`, you need two buttons, one is used to display `MyForm1`, the other is used to call the click event of `MyForm1`, please read the following code carefully.

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
MyForm1^ form1 =(MyForm1^) Application::OpenForms["MyForm1"];
form1->Buttontest->PerformClick();
}

private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
MyForm1^ form1 = gcnew MyForm1;
form1->Show();
}
};
```

Using the above code you have to make sure you use button2 to show another window first and then use button1 to call the click event.

Comment: thank you so much i cannot believe that someone took time to make an example! and yes have a question: what is the meaning of "=(MyForm1^)" in button1_click that you created in MyForm.h ?

Comment: @tonyukuk , About MyForm1^ form1 =(MyForm1^) Application::OpenForms["MyForm1"]; I recommend you to read this documentation, and (MyForm1^) is a type conversion.